# How to change Mandrill's automatic unsubscribe text?

Tags: email, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill API and want to know how I could change the text of the unsubscribe footer, instead of the automatic text. Can I add a link to my email message that leads to the unsubscribe page of Mandrill?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently customize Mandrill's unsubscribe footer, you can just turn it on or off (in Settings => Sending defaults). However, except very special circumstances, you should track unsubscribes, so if you turn the automatic footer off, you can track them with the UNSUB merge tag:

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582947-About-Unsubscribes